# Xamarin Forms 4.1 CalloutAccessoryControlTapped is no more called for tap on annotation view

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms.maps

Recently, a behavior in iOS map annotation changed :

[image]

The event `CalloutAccessoryControlTapped` is no more called whe the user tap on the annotation view. For example if i tap on the red area in the image above. The only way to trigger the event is to tap on the information button to the right.

Is there a way to force `CalloutAccessoryControlTapped` to raise when we tap on the whole surface of the annotation ?

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<View> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control is MKMapView nativeMap)
            {
                if (e.OldElement != null)
                {
                    nativeMap.RemoveAnnotations(nativeMap.Annotations);
                    nativeMap.GetViewForAnnotation = null;
                    nativeMap.CalloutAccessoryControlTapped -= OnCalloutAccessoryControlTapped;
                }

                if (e.NewElement != null)
                {
                    CustomMap = (CustomMap)e.NewElement;

                    nativeMap.GetViewForAnnotation = GetViewForAnnotation;
                    nativeMap.CalloutAccessoryControlTapped += OnCalloutAccessoryControlTapped;
                }
            }
        }

// event delegate
private void OnCalloutAccessoryControlTapped(object sender, MKMapViewAccessoryTappedEventArgs e)
    {
        // ...
    }
```

Comment: Is my solution working to you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add custom a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to that `View` to achieve the effect, here are the steps:

First, define a `ges` in the `CustomMapRenderer` :

```
public class CustomMapRenderer : MapRenderer
{
    UIView customPinView;
    List<CustomPin> customPins;

    UITapGestureRecognizer ges;

    ...
}
```

Then in the `OnDidSelectAnnotationView`, add the `ges` to the `customView`:

```
void OnDidSelectAnnotationView(object sender, MKAnnotationViewEventArgs e)
{
    var customView = e.View as CustomMKAnnotationView;
    customPinView = new UIView();


    Action action = () => {

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(((CustomMKAnnotationView)customView).Url))
        {
            UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(new Foundation.NSUrl(((CustomMKAnnotationView)customView).Url));
        }
    };

    ges = new UITapGestureRecognizer(action);
    customView.AddGestureRecognizer(ges);

    if (customView.MarkerId == "Xamarin")
    {
        customPinView.Frame = new CGRect(0, 0, 200, 84);
        var image = new UIImageView(new CGRect(0, 0, 200, 84));
        image.Image = UIImage.FromFile("xamarin.png");
        customPinView.AddSubview(image);
        customPinView.Center = new CGPoint(0, -(e.View.Frame.Height + 75));
        e.View.AddSubview(customPinView);
    }
}
```

And remove it at `OnDidDeselectAnnotationView`:

```
void OnDidDeselectAnnotationView(object sender, MKAnnotationViewEventArgs e)
{

    var customView = e.View as CustomMKAnnotationView;
    customView.RemoveGestureRecognizer(ges);

    if (!e.View.Selected)
    {
        customPinView.RemoveFromSuperview();
        customPinView.Dispose();
        customPinView = null;
    }
}
```

Refer: [customized-pin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/map/customized-pin#consuming-the-custom-map)

Comment: I need TapGesture to work for customPinView (I have a button inside that area). TapGesture for customView is only called when I click the Pin twice. Any alternative?